# Eclipse with AppEngine plugin adding dependencies

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace `'.png" alt="" />'` with `''`
When running

```
sed -i -e 's/.png" alt="" />//g' funnel.txt
```

I get the following:

```
sed: 1: "s/\.png"\ alt=""\ />//g": bad flag in substitute command: '/'
```

How do I correct the issue?

Comment: Add funnel.txt and your desired output to your question.

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: funnel.txt is the file that has the strings I want to replace.